# Symfony2 form variable not viewing in an included template

Tags: php, templates, symfony

In a bit of a doozy. I'm trying to render a form in a template, which is a template that is included in another template.

In my controller:

```
public function searchInvSumAction(Request $request)
{

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('fromdate','date', array(
                'label' => 'From: ',
                'widget' => 'single_text'
            ))
        ->add('todate','date', array(
                'label' => 'To: ',
                'widget' => 'single_text'
            ))
        ->add('generate','submit')
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('CIRBundle:Reports:index.html.twig', array(
           'invsum' => $form->createView()
        ));

}
```

index.html.twig template:

```
// codes........

     <li>
      <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3">
      <label for="tab3" class="tab">Inventory Summary</label>
      <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">
         {{ include('CIRBundle:Reports:invsum.html.twig') }}
      </div>
    </li>

// more codes...
```

and on the included template invsum.html.twig:

```
{{ form(invsum) }}
```

I get the error message:

```
Variable "invsum" does not exist in CIRBundle:Reports:invsum.html.twig at line 4
```

When I tried rendering the form into invsum.html.twig instead I still get the same error that the variable does not exist. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass variable `invsum` from `index.html.twig` to `invsum.html.twig`

Try

```
{{ include('CIRBundle:Reports:invsum.html.twig', {'invsum': invsum}) }}
```

Comment: Nope, it is still giving me the same error that the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: it should work. Did you clear the cache after adding `invsum` parameter?

Comment: @dmnptr yes I did. still not recognizing the variable.

Comment: Is there a routing complication?

Comment: Can you make `{{ form(invsum) }}` in `index.html.twig`, check if variable exist there.